How to fix "could not find driver" error in laravel 11
I got this error when starting my laravel project:
Illuminate \ Database\ QueryException
could not find driver
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
This is the pict
I tried to remove the semicolon extension=pdo_mysql in php.ini file from the xampp/php folder.
And remove the comments in .env file from
this
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
#DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
#DB_PORT=3306
#DB_DATABASE=laravel
#DB_USERNAME=root
#DB_PASSWORD=

to
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

and got this error instead
select * from sessions where id = rJV8ccVLO8rJ0AsiiomdmMsg5FGKLNq5Asi646pd limit 1
This is the pict after i changed the .env file
It's my first time learning laravel
Is there any solution?

please post full error messages

did the error message change after each of your manipulation ? if so please add those details to your question. You can also try changing SESSION_DRIVER=file.

I just add the error pict i hope it help

Did you check whether the drivers for these database connectors are enabled?

In my case, the extension pdo_sqlite had to be enabled in the php.ini file. On my Linux system, the file was under /etc/php/php.ini. Simply uncomment the line for pdo_sqlite. Enabling this extension also requires it to be installed, which is different for every system. On Ubuntu for example, the package can be installed via sudo apt install php-sqlite3.

Once you have editted .env file and entered the correct database details, run the migrations, it should create the sessions table and other related tables.
Simply run:
php artisan migrate
This should fix the second error you are getting.

set SESSION_DRIVER=file in .env file
